# 2d Vector issues in xCode

Tags: c++, xcode, netbeans, vector

I am trying to teach myself 2d vectors in C++. After reading various textbooks and online forums, I have found the following syntax to be the correct way to declare a 2d vectors with x amount of rows and columns:

```
vector <vector<int> > board(rows, columns);
```

But Xcode returns and error saying that there are no matching constructors. The same exact code does not return errors in netbeans 8.1.

After reading other forums, I have found another way to declare a 2d vector which does not return errors in Xcode:

```
vector< vector<int> > board(rows,vector<int>(columns));
```

What I want to ask is are these the same thing? If they are could someone explain to me why? And if they aren't what are the differences?

Thanks

EDIT:
Although I do have netbeans, I dislike using it. I was merely asking since my friend who is also working on this with me is using it. Regardless, we will be continuing with the second statement. I originally posted the new question here but since this was so poorly asked I decided to create a new one instead. Thanks for being patient. Here's the link:

[Some questions regarding 2d Vectors, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199078/some-questions-regarding-2d-vectors-c)

Comment: Since one of them compiles and the other doesn't, the answer to "are these the same thing" seems rather obvious. No, they're not. And the first doesn't compile on *any* C++ toolchain I'm aware of if both `rows` and `columns` are simply `int`. Nor is netbeans a C++ compiler (it's an IDE).  Post a **complete** sample program, including `#iinclude` list and `main()` that exhibits the problem you're describing, and include with it the back-end toolchain your netbeans config is using.

Comment: *After reading various textbooks and online forums, I have found the following syntax to be the correct way to declare a 2d vectors with x amount of rows and columns:* -- You need to read those books again, or throw them away and get new books, because that is not the way to declare a 2d vector with x amount of rows and columns.

Comment: The first one works on netbeans, but doesn't work on xcode and the second one works on xcode and netbeans. I've been using netbeans the whole semester I'm not sure why this is happening now. I'll post some sample code, this is a part of a larger project so I'll need to write out a new one to show what my issue is.

Comment: Looking forward to it. It should be trivial; only about a half-dozen total lines.